# Take FFT of an Image in Google Go

Tags: go, signal-processing, fft

How do you take the FFT of an image in Google Go?

The Go DSP library (github.com/mjibson/go-dsp/fft) has a function for a 2D FFT with the following signature:

```
func FFT2Real(x [][]float64) [][]complex128
```

How do I convert an image from the standard go image types to float64? Is this the right approach?

Here is a [link to the documentation](http://godoc.org/github.com/mjibson/go-dsp/fft).

Comment: Where did you find this function? https://github.com/mjibson/go-dsp/search?q=ftt2real does not show anything.

Comment: @creack: For example, [package fft `func FFT2Real(x [][]float64) [][]complex128`](http://godoc.org/github.com/r9y9/go-dsp/fft#FFT2Real). FFT2Real returns the 2-dimensional, forward FFT of the real-valued matrix.

Comment: @creack, I added the link.

Comment: My bad, sorry. Ok, I am no specialist, so what do you want in your matrix? Depending on the type of image, you will have different things available. Doc for image.RGBA: `Pix holds the image's pixels, in R, G, B, A order. The pixel at(x, y) starts at Pix[(y-Rect.Min.Y)*Stride + (x-Rect.Min.X)*4].`. This can easily be transformed in a 2 diminutional matrix, but it depends on what data you need.

Comment: @creack: Your search is wrong. You searched for `q=ftt2real`. Try [`https://github.com/mjibson/go-dsp/search?q=fft2real`](https://github.com/mjibson/go-dsp/search?q=fft2real).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options, both involve copying the pixels. You can either use the methods [provided by the `Image` interface](http://golang.org/pkg/image/#Image), namely `At(x,y)` or you can assert the image to one of the image types provided by the `image` packet and access the `Pix` attribute directly.

Since you will most likely be using a Gray image, you could easily assert your image to type `*image.Gray` and access [the pixels directly](http://golang.org/pkg/image/#Gray) but for the sake of abstraction I did not in my example:

```
inImage, _, err := image.Decode(inFile)

// error checking

bounds := inImage.Bounds()

realPixels := make([][]float64, bounds.Dy())

for y := 0; y < bounds.Dy(); y++ {
    realPixels[y] = make([]float64, bounds.Dx())
    for x := 0; x < bounds.Dx(); x++ {
        r, _, _, _ := inImage.At(x, y).RGBA()
        realPixels[y][x] = float64(r)
    }
}
```

This way you read all the pixels of your image `inImage` and store them as `float64` values in a two-dimensional slice, ready to be processed by `fft.FFT2Real`:

```
// apply discrete fourier transform on realPixels.
coeffs := fft.FFT2Real(realPixels)

// use inverse fourier transform to transform fft 
// values back to the original image.
coeffs = fft.IFFT2(coeffs)

// write everything to a new image
outImage := image.NewGray(bounds)

for y := 0; y < bounds.Dy(); y++ {
    for x := 0; x < bounds.Dx(); x++ {
        px := uint8(cmplx.Abs(coeffs[y][x]))
        outImage.SetGray(x, y, color.Gray{px})
    }
}

err = png.Encode(outFile, outImage)
```

In the code above I applied FFT on the pixels stored in `realPixels` and then, to see whether it worked, used inverse FFT on the result. The expected result is the original image.

A full example can be found [here](http://play.golang.org/p/Udd2Yt0V7l).

Comment: Hi @nemo, the example works great. 

I am trying to implement filters using ftt. If a draw the 2D ftt, I get an image that looks like static. I've seen some examples where they get quite interesting patterns in their 2D fft's and then edit them (before applying the inverse fft) as a means to apply filters.

Any clue on what is going on? How to get the "nice-pattern-ffts"?

Comment: Take the example images and see if you can reproduce the patterns. If you can't reproduce them it is likely that you have a bug in your code.